# How can I get my lp printout to *always* be smaller and one sided?

Tags: printing, cups

The default output is double sided and too big.

I can get better output with `lp spec/scenarios_spec.rb -o sides=one-sided -o fit-to-page`

How could I make those options - `-o sides=one-sided -o fit-to-page` - be the default for all printing that I do on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lpoptions` with the `-o` options you want. As the man page says, this sets the defaults for both `lp` and `lpr`.